# How to avoid useless piecewised solutions from sympy

Tags: python, sympy

From

```
from sympy import *
t,r = symbols('t r', real=True, nonnegative=True)
c_x,c_y,a1,a2 = symbols('c_x c_y a1 a2', real=True)
integrate(-r*(a1 - a2)*(c_x*cos(-a1*t + a1 + a2*t) + c_y*sin(-a1*t + a1 + a2*t) + r)/2,(t,0,1))
```

I obtain the piecewise solution

```
Piecewise((-a1*c_x*r*cos(a2)/2 - a1*c_y*r*sin(a2)/2 - a1*r**2/2 + a2*c_x*r*cos(a2)/2 + a2*c_y*r*sin(a2)/2 + a2*r**2/2, Eq(a1, a2)), (-a1*r**2/2 + a2*r**2/2 - c_x*r*sin(a1)/2 + c_x*r*sin(a2)/2 + c_y*r*cos(a1)/2 - c_y*r*cos(a2)/2, True))
```

[image]

which does not need to be piecewised because if `a1`=`a2` both expressions are 0, therefore the second expression is actually a global non-piecewise solution.

So my first question is: can I make sympy give me the non-piecewise solution? (by setting some option or anything else)

Regardless of the above mentioned possibility, since I can accept that `a1` is not equal to `a2` (it is a limit case of no interest), is there a way to tell sympy of such assumption? (again in order to obatin the non-piecewise solution)

Thanks in advance from a sympy novice.

P.S. For the same problem Maxima gives directly the non-piecewise solution.

Comment: there is a keyword `conds` of which the default is "piecewise". It can also be set to "separate" or "none". The latter is probably in the right direction. However, as it is a definite integral, probably you can try the keyword `manual=True` as well..

Comment: @Uvar Thanks, all the 3 options work in this case, altough I don't understand exactly what they do, and the documentation doesn't help very much. For example the option `conds='separate'` should give the solution as a tuple instead of piecewise, but gives a unique (but correct) solution.

Comment: Moved to answers as it seems to have done the trick. I am just as confused as you are as to the `conds='separate'` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a keyword conds of which the default is "piecewise". It can also be set to "separate" or "none". However, as it is a definite integral, probably you can try the keyword manual=True as well..

If you set the keyword to `conds='separate'`, it should return a distinct tuple with the convergence conditions. I tried it, only gives a single solution. I don't know yet why this behaviour is not as expected.
The `conds='none'` keyword should not return the convergence conditions, just the solution. This is I think what you are looking for.

Another option, which is only valid in context of definite integrals, is another keyword `manual=True`. This mimics integrating by hand, conveniently "forgetting" about checking for convergence conditions.